# Eureka authentication method and UI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Is there any authentication method (user and password) and UI for it avalible for Netflix's server registry library Eureka? I'm looking for something like Spring Boot Admin's login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ui page which you can see just enter your **host:port** in browser. But it just shows info about registered clients, nothing you can do more. And for authentication you can use basic spring security. If you enable basic security with a user name and password, that ui asks you for it when you try to get to page. Additionally you should supply those username and password for registering clients too.

Comment: Do you have an example of the client registration?

Comment: @PauloSalgado it is basic authentication. For client property when you add eureka server just add username and password like that: **http :/ /username:password@host:port/eureka/** and for eureka server property: **security.basic.enabled:true**, **security.user.name:your user**, **security.user.password:your password**

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other Spring Boot Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ServeurCloudEurekaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServeurCloudEurekaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Start your App and enter your **host:port** in browser